# find string in file using bash

Tags: linux, bash

I need to find strings matching some `regexp pattern` and represent the search result as array for iterating through it with loop ), do I need to use `sed` ? In general I want to replace some strings but analyse them before replacing.

Comment: what does `analyze` mean? Can you give examples? `sed` is def one of the options you have

Comment: Usually you'd use `grep` to search.  Can you explain your problem more clearly?

Comment: `grep` for searching, `sed` for search and substitution, `awk` for search, complex analysis and substitution. If you can describe your problem clearly right tool for the job can be suggested.

Comment: ok, I want to write a bash script that replace some strings(that meets the condition) in a files   and save report(important) about substitutions

Comment: If you want to see each replacement in its context (this is how I understand _analyse them before replacing_), you might as well use a genuine text editor like `vim`.

Comment: This sounds like a job for perl or awk, not bash.

Comment: @ZanLynx Just because people would _traditionally_ use perl or awk for this doesn't make bash a bad choice. The cases where awk is stronger (for instance, automated FD management) don't really apply here.

Comment: @MickeyTin Please have a look at some of the revisions to the answer you accepted -- it's much stronger now than it was originally.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `sed` and `diff`:

```
sed -i.bak 's/this/that/' input
diff input input.bak
```

GNU `sed` will create a backup file before substitutions, and `diff` will show you those changes. However, if you are not using GNU `sed`:

```
mv input input.bak
sed 's/this/that/' input.bak > input
diff input input.bak
```

Another method using `grep`:

```
pattern="/X"
subst=that
while IFS='' read -r line; do
    if [[ $line = *"$pattern"* ]]; then
        echo "changing line: $line" 1>&2
        echo "${line//$pattern/$subst}"
    else
        echo "$line"
    fi  
done < input > output
```

Comment: Invoking `grep` once per line makes this _extremely_ inefficient for absolutely no reason at all. `if [[ $line = *pattern* ]]; then ...`, or, if the pattern is a regex, put it in a variable and use `[[ $line =~ $re ]]`

Comment: ...also, it should be `read -r`, not bare `read`, unless you want escape sequences expanded.

Comment: ...also, reopening the `output` file once per line to be written to it (as is done by using `>>` on the individual lines) is _also_ unnecessary inefficiency.

Comment: ...also, `sed -i` is not a POSIX-standard option -- it'll work on GNU systems, but that's no guarantee that it'll work everywhere. In-line replacements are better done with `ex` or `ed`, both of which are POSIX-standard tools.

Comment: ...also, `echo $line` (unquoted, as it is here) introduces bugs; for instance, if the input contains `*` as a word, the output will contain a list of files in the local directory in its place.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, thanks for the great info! I changed some of the things you pointed out.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, if I change more it will look like yours :)

Comment: ...by the way, `sed "s/$pattern/$subst/g"` isn't generally a safe thing to do -- what if `$pattern` or `$subst` contains a `/`? What if `$pattern` is a regex that isn't self-evaluating?

Comment: `echo "$line" | grep "$pattern"` could be more succinctly (but still inefficiently) written as `grep "$pattern" <<<"$line"`.

Comment: ...anyhow -- if you fix your answer to not have serious efficiency or correctness issues, I'll gladly delete mine and +1 yours. It's more important to have the best possible answer prominently displayed than to fight about who gets credit. :)

Answer (score 3):

The best way to do this would be to use `grep` to get the lines, and populate an array with the result using newline as the internal field separator:

```
#!/bin/bash

# get just the desired lines
results=$(grep "mypattern" mysourcefile.txt)

# change the internal field separator to be a newline
IFS=$'/n'

# populate an array from the result lines
lines=($results)

# return the third result
echo "${lines[2]}"
```

You could build a loop to iterate through the results of the array, but a more traditional and simple solution would just be to use bash's iteration:

```
for line in $lines; do
  echo "$line"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

FYI: Here is a similar concept I created for fun.  I thought it would be good to show how to loop a file and such with this. This is a script where I look at a Linux sudoers file check that it contains one of the valid words in my valid_words array list. Of course it ignores the comment "#" and blank "" lines with sed. In this example, we would probably want to just print the Invalid lines only but this script prints both.

```
#!/bin/bash

# -- Inspect a sudoer file, look for valid and invalid lines.

file="${1}"
declare -a valid_words=( _Alias = Defaults includedir )

actual_lines=$(cat "${file}" | wc -l)
functional_lines=$(cat "${file}" | sed '/^\s*#/d;/^\s*$/d' | wc -l)

while read line ;do

    # -- set the line to nothing "" if it has a comment or is empty line.
    line="$(echo "${line}" | sed '/^\s*#/d;/^\s*$/d')"

    # -- if not set to nothing "", check if the line is valid from our list of valid words.
    if ! [[ -z "$line" ]] ;then

        unset found 
        for each in "${valid_words[@]}" ;do
            found="$(echo "$line" | egrep -i "$each")"
            [[ -z "$found" ]] || break;
        done

        [[ -z "$found" ]] && { echo "Invalid=$line"; sleep 3; } || echo "Valid=$found"

    fi

done < "${file}"

echo "actual lines: $actual_lines  funtional lines: $functional_lines"
```